# My OpenGL C++ Eclipse project suddenly stopped recognizing glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, eclipse-cdt

My OpenGL C++ project suddenly stopped recognizing glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW). I went to dinner and then my project would not build.

I am working using Windows 7 64bit C++ in Eclipse with the CDT plugin. In order to set up the static link libraries I went: Project properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries > Add: glut32, glu32, opengl32, and gdi32

Here is the code:

```
#ifdef __APPLE_CC__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
...
void initialize() { 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(-45.0, 4.0 / 3.0, 1, 40);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // <--------------- 'GL_MODELVIEW' was not declared in this scope
                                // full error: ..\main.cpp:103:15: error: 'GL_MODELVIEW' was not declared in this scope
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(5,5,5, 0,0,0, 0,-1,0);
}
```

I have re-downloated all of the OpenGL libraries, recreated the project, re-linked the libraries to the project, and cleaned the project and re-built. I have even re-downloaed eclipse and re-installed the C++ plugin.

Comment: How drunk did you get at dinner? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it appears that gl.h is not included with the installation resources provided for OpenGL. The problem was that somehow gl.h was edited (removing GL_MODELVIEW) inside of MinGW\include. Re-downloading the compiler, and installing it solved the problem. For those who need the download information for MinGW (because it took me about 20 mins to find it) here it is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/?source=dlp

Comment: Are you sure you weren't drunk when you returned to the computer?  Or maybe you have a cat =)  They're notorious for pushing just the right keys to deleting important lines of code while you're away.